# Sharing a printer to a different subnet

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding

I have a Motorola MG7550 cable modem/router with a hardwired PC on one port and a Google Nest mesh network hardwired on the other. All wireless functionality on the MG7550 is disabled. I am trying to make a printer connected wirelessly to the Nest mesh visible to the PC. Should it be possible to enable port forwarding for a static IP on the Nest mesh to allow visibility to that device from the MG7550 network?

A few additional points:

1) I would have no concerns about security since all of this traffic is still behind the MG7550 firewall.

2) I can't put the Mesh network in bridge mode because that disables the mesh capability of that network :(

3) There is a similar question [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/how-can-i-share-my-printer-on-different-nat): There was an answer provided by Scherard to add a new route on the outside router (MG7550) which seems like it would be a good solution - however, it appears that the MG7550 only has port forwarding between external and internal IPs

4) Physical limitations prevent the PC from being directly connected to the Nest mesh router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can setup the port-forwarding on the Nest for the printing protocols you don't need a route on the Motorola at all.
You can set a route directly on the PC to deliver traffic for the printer to the WAN IP-address of the Nest.

Something like `route add -p ip_printer wan_ip_nest` should do the trick (assuming Windows 10).
The -p makes the route persist across reboots. The command must be given from a command prompt or powershell prompt with "run as administrator".

Comment: Great answer - I got it working - thank you Tonny!  I have a couple follow up questions.  I didn't actually need to run the route command - I was able to access the printer by mapping directly to the IP address of the Nest router after forwarding ports.  Is there any benefit of adding the route command to use a different IP to map the printer?  Also, even though I think the port forwarding is not a risk because it's all behind the MG7550 firewall, I'd still like to limit the ports being mapped (I just mapped them all).  Any idea what ports are used for printing?

Comment: @Oiler_no11 Using the ip-address of the Nest directly like this works in this case too. But if your Nest was doing full routing you would need the route to let the PC know that the subnet behind the Nest can be reached via the Nest. (But you would probably want a route for the whole subnet in that case, not just for that printer.). Printing ports can vary depending on model of printer. Best ask a separate question about that and specify the brand/model of printer in that. (Aka "What ports to open on firewall to print to printer XXX".)